# Correct wait to fetch queue of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

Ok, so, I have a java class in which every method must run in a thread.
only one thread is executed per time and at a specific time.
I've implemented like this, with a inner class that extends Thread.

```
private class MyOperation extends Thread {

    public static final String M1 = "method1";
    public static final String M2 = "method2";
    public static final String M3 = "method3";

    protected long scheduledStartTime = 0;
    private String type;

    public MyOperation(String type, long milliSecondsToWait) {
        this.type = type;
        scheduledStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mlliSecondsToWait;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        switch(type){
        case M1:
            doMethod1();
            break;
        case M2:
            doMethod3();
            break;
        case M3:
            doMethod3();
            break;

        }
        setCurrentOperation(null);
    }
}



private void setCurrentOperation(MyOperation task) {
        synchronized (currentOperation) {
            this.currentOperation = task;
        }
    }
```

then I have the Thread queue and the current running thread

```
private MyOperation currentOperation;
private Queue <MyOperation> operationList;
```

And I'm fetching tasks like this:

```
    private void fetchTasks() {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if(currentOperation == null && !operationList.isEmpty()) {
                    currentOperation = getOperation();
                    while(currentOperation.scheduledStartTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        // do nothing, wait for proper time;
                    }
                    currentOperation.start();
                }
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
    private MyOperation getOperation() {
    synchronized (operationList) {
        return operationList.remove();
    }
}
```

and I'm adding thread to the queue like this, for example:

```
addOperation(new MyOperation(M1, 5));

    private void addOperation(MyOperation task) {
    synchronized (operationList) {
        operationList.add(task);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

**Is there a better way to run each method in a diffent thread?**

**Is this way of fetching the threads queue correct?**

Thank you very much

Comment: Your switch statement looks like a desperate cry for polymorphism.  Instead of having one MyOperation class that accepts a 'type' argument in its constructor, why not have three different MyOperationXxxxxx classes that implement a common interface or inherit from a common abstract class?  That is to say, why not use Java types to represent your application's 'type' concept?

Comment: Yeah I also agree this is kind of ugly.
Basically I did this because I wanted all the methods in a class to run as in different thread.
And also because of the "setCurrentOperation(null)", that must be called at the end of the run() method

Answer (score 0):

Just a little thing: if your `operationsList` is empty or the `currentOperation` is not null your thread starts going in circles really fast.
You could use `Thread.wait()` and `.notify()` to avoid this.

Also you are using `currentOperation` with and without `synchronized`. This could get you into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Have you condsidered using a ScheduledExecutorService (java.util.concurrent) to schedule your tasks?